# Contar quantos id tem na tabela baseado em outro dado

Tags: c#, gráfico, asp-net-core

Olá
Estou tentando fazer um gráfico em aspnetcore usando EF, 
Tenho uma tabela Eventos nela contem uma FK IdArea que determina a área do evento
Queria contar quantos eventos tem de cada IdArea, por exemplo quantos eventos tem da área de TI, O gráfico em si está funcional o problema está na lógica que não estou conseguindo entender!
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Segue as tentativas !
OBS.: Total Evento é são os testes que fiz o SUM funciona o gráfico mas claro que ele soma o que tem dentro do campo então não é o caso!
Não da nenhum erro de compilação mas não aparece o informações no gráfico

```
public IEnumerable<GraficoViewModel> ListaGrafico(int IdArea, int IdEvento)
    {
        var lista = _contexto.Evento.Include(a => a.Area)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                  .Select(y =>  new GraficoViewModel
                  {
                      IdEvento = y.First().Id,
                      Descricao = y.First().Area.Descricao,
                      //TotalEvento = y.Sum(a =>a.IdArea)
                      //TotalEvento = y.Count(c =>c.IdArea == IdArea )
                      TotalEvento = y.Where(c =>c.IdArea == IdArea ).Count()
                  }).ToList();


                  }).ToList();

        return lista;
    }
```

Comment: Olá @Piscinão, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta caso ela resolva o seu problema. Já o "marcar como útil" é opcional e pode ser usado por qualquer pessoa.

Answer (score 1):

É preciso entender o que faz o `GroupBy`. O que vc estava fazendo era agrupar os eventos pelo seu `id`, o que criava um grupos de eventos com o mesmo `id`. Neste caso, seria criado um grupo para cada evento, já que o `id` deve ser único. Ao alterar o `GroupBy` para `idArea` (suponho que seja essa a propriedade em `Evento` que identifica a área do evento), criamos grupos com eventos da mesma área.

A seguir, precisamos entender o resultado do `GroupBy`. O que é obtido deste método são grupos, cada um com os eventos da mesma área. Sendo assim, o `Select` é pelos grupos tais e não pelos eventos. Iterando pelos grupos, podemos pegar a área do 1o item de cada grupo (já que todos têm a mesma área) para identificar o seu nome e fazer o `Count` de eventos no grupo.

```cs
public IEnumerable<GraficoViewModel> ListaGrafico(int IdArea, int IdEvento) // IdEvento não é relevante para o seu método
{
    var lista = _contexto.Evento
                         .Include(a => a.Area)
                         .GroupBy(x => x.idArea)
                         .Select(y =>  new GraficoViewModel
                         {
                             Descricao = y.First().Area.Descricao,
                             TotalEvento = y.First().Count()
                         })
                         .ToList();

    return lista;
}
```